# How can I pull textfield inputs from my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, textfield

I'm using Google Analytics on my site to track events such as button clicks, one of which is a subscribe button. Though, I noticed the number of subscribers is far less than the number of clicks on the subscribe button.

Is it possible to find out the inputs that have gone into the textfields in the past few days? I've read about using the tag manager in GA which I'll try but I want to know if it's possible to know all data that has gone through the texfields either using GA or another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using Google Tag Manager.

By creating a Javascript variable which accesses the value attribute of the field - which is where the user fills in data.

Using the code below, the value attribute of the form with ID 'inputfieldID' is accessed.

`function() {
  var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#inputFieldId');
  return field ? field.value : undefined;
}`

credit: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Be aware you must not be sending any PII, like email , phone number directly into the GA. You mush hash it

Comment: Per current TOS hash would have to be SHA256 or better. While this is achievable in JS it might create a performance issue. Also of course having a hashed value is not particularly useful if you want to learn the value of a text field.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

On the click event of the button run this, either on onClick event or after your script runs

```
    <input type="button" name="subscribe" onclick="ga('send','event', { eventCategory: 'Button-clicked', eventAction: 'Subscribe', eventLabel: 'Subscribe_Button-clicked', transport:'beacon'});" value="Subscribe" />
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Thanks but I already have this code on my website. It's used for tracking the clicks on the subscribe button. I'm trying to pull the values from the textfield.